# Eigenvalue condition when one eigenvector is [0 0 ... 0]

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Considering the eigenvalue condition:

$$\kappa(\lambda) = \frac{1}{u^Tv}$$
where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ and $u$ and $v$ resp. left and right eigenvector of $A$ for $\lambda$.

What happens if $u = [0 \ 0 \ ... \ 0]$ or $v = [0 \ 0 \ ... \ 0]$ ? Is $\kappa(\lambda)$ equal to $0$ or simply undefined ?

Comment: The zero vector is per definitionem not considered as an eigenvector.

Comment: Oh yes of course.. should have thought twice before asking. Thank you. And just another quick question, what if we have an infinity of eigenvectors for an eigenvalue ? Which one do we pick to compute the condition ?

Comment: Sorry,  but your condition is unknown to me.

Comment: Ok, no prob. Thank you again.

Comment: What exactly is $κ(λ)$? Relative to what type of perturbations? Is there somewhere the condition $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$?

Comment: @LutzL Perturbations of the matrix, that is A(eps) = A + eps * E and yes exactly the vectors must be normalised. I actually just realised that and it answers my second question right ?

Comment: For vectors spaces over the fields $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, there is *always* an infinite number of eigenvectors for each eigenvalue.

Comment: Because if $v$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$, then $c*v$ with $c\in\mathbb{C}$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda$, is that it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Michael Hoppe:

> The zero vector is per definition not considered as an eigenvector